# C# Date manipulation

Tags: c#, datetime

am I doing this wrong?

```
                DateTime previousDay = new DateTime(year, month, day);
                string test1 = previousDay.ToString();
                previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
                string test2 = previousDay.ToString();
                previousDay.AddDays(-1);
                string test3 = previousDay.ToString();
```

For some reason probably obvious to most people, the date doesn't change from test1 to test3.
Help please!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DateTime` is immutable - when you call `Subtract` it doesn't change the target of the call, it *returns* a new value:

```
DateTime previousDay = new DateTime(year, month, day);
string test1 = previousDay.ToString();
previousDay = previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
string test2 = previousDay.ToString();
previousDay = previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
string test3 = previousDay.ToString();
```

Although I'd use the `-` operator, and `TimeSpan.FromDays`:

```
DateTime previousDay = new DateTime(year, month, day);
string test1 = previousDay.ToString();
previousDay = previousDay - TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
string test2 = previousDay.ToString();
previousDay = previousDay - TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
string test3 = previousDay.ToString();
```

Or better yet, use `AddDays`:

```
DateTime previousDay = new DateTime(year, month, day);
string test1 = previousDay.ToString();
previousDay = previousDay.AddDays(-1);
string test2 = previousDay.ToString();
previousDay = previousDay.AddDays(-1);
string test3 = previousDay.ToString();
```

Or even better yet, use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) :)

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
string test1 = previousDay.ToString();
date = date.PlusDays(-1);
string test2 = previousDay.ToString();
date = date.PlusDays(-1);
string test3 = previousDay.ToString();
```

Or:

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(year, month, day);
string test1 = previousDay.ToString();
date = date + Period.FromDays(-1);
string test2 = previousDay.ToString();
date = date + Period.FromDays(-1);
string test3 = previousDay.ToString();
```

Comment: Hmm I said it was probably obvious to most people! Thanks for such a complete answer!

Comment: @bukko  please set the above post as "answer"

Answer (score 2):

:) This returns a new datetime but doesnT change the caller objects value

```
previousDay.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: we got skeeted again. unite! the underdogs of the Stack, let s downvote him!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you aren't actually changing the value of previousDay.

You need to actually assign the new value:

```
previousDay = previousDay.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is immutable, meaning each call to `Subtract` and `AddDays` actually returns a new instance with the values. `previousDay` will never change.

Answer (score 1):

Try: (as DateTime like string class is immutable)

```
DateTime previousDay = new DateTime(year, month, day);                 
string test1 = previousDay.ToString();                 
previousDay = previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract return timespan with the new value. you keep using the old value.

more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Modify this line:

```
previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

as

```
previousDay = previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

OR

if you don't want to change previous variable

```
DateTime updatedPreviousDay = previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are simply subtracting the new timespan from the datetime variable but not assigning the result to the datetime variable. So, the changes will not affect to the datetime variable. So, better do like this.

```
previousDay = previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
string test2 = previousDay.ToString();

or

string test2 = (previousDay.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0))).ToString();
```